# Android /data/log folder queries

Tags: android, storage

I am getting a `low storage notification` from `android` on my `Samsung tablet` , and due to this my application is unable to write on a file , perform database operations like `insert`.

By searching i found out that , by dialing `*#9900#` and `deleting logcat/dumpstate` solves the problem , and it worked too.

There is also a method named `onLowMemory()` , which gets called when whole device memory is low, and may be it will work in my case , and I will show a notification in my app.

But my question is , whether android itself clears data from `/data/log` folder or not ? if yes , what is the time period ? Or we always have to use `*#9900#` to delete data from `/data/log` folder ?

**Device name : Samsung Galaxy Note 10.0** 
**Android version : 4.0.4**

Comment: Which device and Android version do you use? There was a bug in Cyanogenmod which did not clear the logs and caused a low storage warning.

Comment: I am not using Cyanogenmod , device is Samsung Galaxy Note 10.0 and android version 4.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

According to google results it seems like this is a Samsung related problem.
Most of the files inside `/data/log` are `dumpstate` files which means they store the state of the system/driver which crashed or had to be restarted for whatever reason.

These file will never deleted by the system because they contain information which could be used to fix the problem. Usually the folder should never get that big but it seems like it's a common problem on some Samsung devices. I guess they had a bug in a driver for some firmware versions.

Here is an related question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48279/what-are-these-dumpstate-logs